# scaffolding in CakePHP without the bake command

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, scaffolding

I am having trouble making a CakePHP scaffold controller. I keep getting this error:

> The action index is not defined in BookmarksController

I have a basic table class.

```
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
class BookmarksTable extends Table{
{
```

And this is the entity class

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;
class Bookmark extends Entity
{
}
```

finally this is the controller

```
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;

class BookmarksController extends AppController{
    var $scaffold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Scaffolding doesn't exist

From [the 3.0 migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#scaffold-removed):

> Scaffold Removed
>
> The dynamic scaffolding in CakePHP has been removed
> from CakePHP core. It was infrequently used, and never intended for
> production use. An improved scaffolding plugin, named CRUD, can be
> found here: https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud